# Showing (custom) dimension as percentage in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm setting up a custom dimension "Area" (or similar) with the possible values "HQ", "Store", "Other" ... so far, all is good. This data is tied to the actual pageview.

For the record, it's done through the equivalent of the following snippet:

```
        ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'dimension1': '...'
        });
```

Following this, in GA, I want to review the page views for a certain URL, and see something to the effect of:

```
Results for /hello-world

Area    Percentage   [more columns?]
HQ      45%          ...
Store   35%          ...
Other   20%          ...
```

Is it possible using standard GA configuration? How can it be done?

Comment: Note: A table view is not strictly necessary, (but I suppose is the most probable), a pie chart or anything similar would be sufficient as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about how to use the  Google analytics website and is not programing related.

Comment: @DaImTo how about moving it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's this simple... there's a pie chart button on the page views page (or *view*?), just click that and select your secondary dimension. Done!

[image: Toolbox on GA showing Pie Chart view]